# React redux update state onClick function with multiple actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to update redux state, the problem i run into is the mapStateToProps is not being update when onclick function being executed with multiple actions. I know actions are running asynchronously and thats why state is not being update on time. is there away to overcome this issue

code Example

when OnClickFunction is executed, getCase action takes this.props.filters.active_case_page as a page number 
and nexPage action changes the active_case_page index, but the issue here is that this.props.getCases still has the old value of this.props.filters.active_case_page when getCase action executes

```
OnClickFunction = () => {
    this.props.nextPage(this.props.filters.active_case_page);
    this.props.getCases(this.props.filters.active_case_page,'All','dateCreated',false,null,'5a9ee9fa88406eeeebabbd1f')
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        filters: state.doctors.filters,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({

        nextPage:nextPage,
        getCases:getCases
    },dispatch)
}

export function nextPage(){

    return{
        type:"NEXT_PAGE"
    }
}

export function getCases(pageNum,filterType,filterOption,isSearchOn,searchText,doctor_id){

    return function(dispatch){
        axios.get("/api/getCases/"+pageNum+"/"+filterType+"/"+filterOption+"/"+isSearchOn+"/"+searchText+"/"+doctor_id)
            .then(function(response){
                dispatch({type:"GET_CASES",payload:response.data});
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                dispatch({type:"GET_CASES_REJECTED",payload:err});
            })
    }
}

export function doctorsReducers(state={
    customer_cases:[],
    filters:{
        active_case_page:0,
        selected_cases_filter:'dateCreated',
        filter_options: 'All',
        isCaseSearchOn:false,
        search_cases:'',
    }

}, action){
    switch(action.type){

        case "NEXT_PAGE":
        // return the state and copy of boos array from state
            return {
                ...state,
                filters:{
                    ...state.filters,
                    active_case_page:state.filters.active_case_page+1,
                }

            }
        break;

        case "GET_CASES":
        // return the state and copy of boos array from state
            return {
                ...state,
                customer_cases:[...action.payload[0]],
            }
        break;

    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: I cant understand what is the problem you are experiencing, can you edit your question and be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is not a mapStateToProps function in your example code.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Read it 3 times and also don't get your problem. What does your component look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you've made your question clearer, it looks like you're looking for a way to dispatch the second action once the first action was already completed.

I would probably use `componentWillReceiveProps` in this way:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    const {filters: {active_case_page}, getCases} = nextProps;
    if (active_case_page !== this.props.filters.active_case_page){
      getCases(active_case_page,'All','dateCreated',false,null,'5a9ee9fa88406eeeebabbd1f'
    }
}
```

But IMO, the whole pattern isn't pretty good.
I would put both of the actions in one action and handle everything together (unless there's a functionality missing in your question because currently I dont see any reason to separate this action to two actions)

Comment: Thank you for your input, correct, I am trying to dispatch the second action once the first action was already completed. i agree both of function should be handled together in this case. However lets say there is more functionality where i have to separate the actions, is using componentWillReceiveProps the only way to achieve sync execution

Comment: Since the first action your'e dispatching is an action that only changes your local state and not a request to the server, that's the way I would recommend. If you were waiting for a response from the server to dispatch another action than I would recommend a promise/async await but that currently isn't the issue...